# Publish React component to NPM issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package

It is my first time publishing the react component to NPM. I used "microbundle" to help me publish my project. After publishing I installed and tried it in another React project. But it got the error[image]

And this is my GitHub link: https://github.com/arthurHui/react-alldate-picker

Can anyone can help me? Thank you guys!